# Typecasting in Java with respect to if statement

Tags: java, casting

Why does this code not work? Specifically, why does the typecast done outside of the if statement does not hold inside of it.

```
private SuperType currObj;

public void someMethod(SuperType currObj){

    if(currObj instanceof aSubType){ 
        currObj = (aSubType) currObj;
        if (true){
            currObj.someMethodofaSubtype();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have some mixing of variable names in there that can be confusing.  You can help specify which is which via 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `currObj = (aSubType) currObj` doesn't really have any net effect.  In order to call `someMethodofaSubtype()`, the compiler wants to know that the object really is of type `aSubType`.  The cast doesn't really change the underlying object.  Casting and then storing the result of the cast as a new variable of type `aSubType` would do the trick. You probably want something like:

```
aSubType subCurrObj = (aSubType) currObj;
subCurrObj.someMethodofaSubtype();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the type cast to have effect you need to store the reference in a variable of the correct type. You've cast from SuperType to aSubType, but then you store the result in a SuperType variable which automatically casts back up.

You want:

```
aSubType subObject = (aSubType)currObj;
```